# Date time type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need storage 2 colums with date_time in my postgresql DB table.

```
date_time            date_time_human
676484556463346      09.06.2017 9:38:00
```

date_time - like oracle timestamp( this date in seconds)
date_time_human - date in normal form

What type of field should be?

```
INSERT INTO tabl (date_time, date_time_human) VALUES(now(), now())
```

Comment: There is no need for two columns. Use a single `timestamp` column and convert it to whatever display format you want, when you _select_ the data.

Comment: I have this task on my job and I am new in Postgresql

Comment: This has nothing to do with PostgreSQL; the answer is the same for every DBMS: this tasks makes no sense and violates database normalization rules.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you have the same value in these fields, then there is no sense in starting it twice.
Create one field of type timestamp. And in seconds you can output and record using functions.
[Data Type Formatting Functions](http://Https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)